# Pre-receive hook file displaying unwanted message while executing the hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, githooks

GitLab version - `9.3.6`

Recently I added the `pre-receive` hook for blocking the binary file pushing. I can get the expected out in my gitlab testing server machine (below image)

[Testing Server side displaying message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRQxa.png)

I added the same hook file on the live server machine. But I got another extra line (below) in displaying the message.

[Live server side displaying message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzXDV.png)

Actually, my hook is working properly. But there is an extra line displaying in the message. I am sure, there no extra printing statement on my hook file.

My commit message is

```
remote: hooks/pre-receive:3: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec in PATH, mode 040777        

remote: Hello there! We have restricted the binary files (.exe, .dll, .zip, .7z, .deb, .cab, .gz, .pkg, .iso) that are pushed into GitLab.        
remote: Your changes contain following file(s) from origin commit c7a151fb to a4e7c31c. Kindly remove the following file(s) and try again.        
remote:     NewTest.dll
```

How can I remove the line `hooks/pre-receive:3: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec in PATH, mode 040777` from that message line?

Comment: Can you remove this dll file from your commit ?

Comment: @hezanathos If I remove the dll file means, I can able to commit to that branch. But I moto is display the error message properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning indicates that `/opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec` is world writable. This is a security issue because it is part of the PATH environment the hook apparently runs with. This means that anyone with access to the server can put executable files into that directory, possibly shadowing legitimate commands with malicious ones. If these commands are then used from within a hook, anyone can gain the privileges of the user running the hook.

To fix this, you should make the indicated libexec directory non world writable:

```
chmod o-w /opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. By your answer, I overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this issue by using `sudo chmod go-w /opt/gitlab`, `sudo chmod go-w /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin` and `sudo chmod go-w /opt/gitlab/embedded`

I give the write permission in the path displayed in the error. Finally, Its works.